# Resource Dictionary unable to catalog Converters

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I am trying to pull our Converters into a common location at the top of the application. When I do so I end up with the following error:

> SourceDefaultValueConverter is not supported in a Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) project.

This is the App.xaml that is throwing the error:

```
<Application x:Class="MSMS.DataCollector.App.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:App="clr-namespace:App"
             xmlns:commonControls="clr-namespace:CommonControls;assembly=CommonControls"
             StartupUri="LoginWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <App:NinjectServiceLocator x:Key="ServiceLocator" />
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Resources">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Converters.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <commonControls:FieldLayoutRuntimeControlConverter x:Key="FieldLayoutConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I simply add the resource directly in a UserControl it works correctly

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <commonControls:FieldLayoutRuntimeControlConverter x:Key="FieldLayoutConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one resource (`ServiceLocator`) outside the `ResourceDictionary`. Move it alongisde your `FieldLayoutConverter` resource. I'm not sure that's resulting in your issue, but it's certainly wrong and may be confusing WPF (which, alas, is not hard to do).

Comment: I did get a little further after this, and hadn't had a chance to update it. There does indeed seem to be a limitation in that respect. I am investigating how to make the Ninject resource work in a more complimentary manner to the regular resource dictionaries.